# Setting style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" to parent layout and style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" to buttons make them invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I followed Android recommendation and set `style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"`  to parent layout and `style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` to buttons. 
So now my layout is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But after setting the style, these buttons have become invisible, although I can still click on them.
Please tell me what is wrong.
**Edit: Additional details**
Well, I've just created a new project specifically to test this layout and surprisingly it indeed does work.
So to be more precise, actually, I dynamically add this layout to another one, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_panel_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- some other stuff -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

LinearLayout buttonsPanelContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_panel_container);

View buttonPanelView = null;
if(chosenValueType.equals("some_type")) {

    buttonPanelView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_buttons_panel, null);

    Button Button1 = (Button) buttonPanelView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button Button2 = (Button) buttonPanelView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button2.setOnClickListener(this);

} else if (chosenRawValueType.equals("another_type") { 
    //...

ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) buttonsPanelContainer;
insertPoint.addView(buttonPanelView, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Sorry to not mention it earlier, I didn't think it could be the case.
So what's wrong?

Comment: @Heyyou I think those are inbuilt style

Comment: @Heyyou Yes, i've. I have used `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` for borderless button style

Comment: Android studio recommendation: Buttons in button bars should be borderless; use style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" (and ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle on the parent)

Comment: I have tried this layout, its showing me three buttons. I didn't see any issues.

Comment: By the way, in preview tab they're shown as they should

Comment: I just tested your code. it works. Did you applied any other theme in manifest?

Comment: Well, I tested this layout separately in a new project and surprisingly it works. So I edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to use

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

instead of

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided example works for me as well. Searching for this style attribute I found this example: https://developer.android.com/samples/BorderlessButtons/res/layout/sample_main.html
Here you can read to apply the style to every button, which you did in the example you gave. So my implication is that something is covering your buttons or the text on the button is set to white (or the background color of your app).