# Creating array of button programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want 20 buttons in rows in a table layout. Current code for a button is like this (they are repeated):

```
<Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@color/colorGreen"
                android:text="1" />
```

How can I obtain the same in code. Specially I don't know how the style element is working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int ButtonStyle = R.style.Your_Button_Style;    
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
 layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,ButtonStyle), 
    null, ButtonStyle);
    btn.setText(" "+i);
    btn.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(10, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layout.addView(btn);
}



 <style name="Your_Button_Style" parent="@android:style/Theme">
<item name="buttonBarStyle">@android:style/ButtonBar</item>
<item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
</style>
```

For Details :
[Setting style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" to parent layout and style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" to buttons make them invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603533/setting-style-androidattr-buttonbarstyle-to-parent-layout-and-style-androi)

Comment: why you find linear layout inside the for loop everytime?

Comment: Oh! sorry i was some busy . now i have changed.

Comment: how to refer to this style from code: ?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle

Comment: I have updated code.but i can't check ,please check and reply.